# How can you trigger a Jenkins master build from GitHub issue comments?

Tags: jenkins, github

We are allowing customers to manage infrastructure using Jenkins by specifying configuration in GitHub; when the configuration is merged to master a deployment pipeline runs to reconcile the configuration.

If there is an issue with the pipeline we want to raise this by creating an issue in GitHub describing what went wrong and allowing customers to comment `/apply` to rerun the pipeline. We are currently able to trigger the pipeline with PR comments (after ticking the `Issue comments` box in our webhook configuration) but issue comments are not being picked up.

Is it possible to trigger a pipeline on issue comments in Jenkins?

Jenkins version: 2.219

Comment: this is more of a github question than a jenkins one. I would suggest updating the tags to include that for better answers

Comment: The docs claim this works the same for issues and PRs https://docs.github.com/en/developers/webhooks-and-events/webhooks/webhook-events-and-payloads#issue_comment. This isn't default Jenkins behaviour afaik so sounds like you're using a Jenkins plug-in to trigger from comments and it's perhaps that which isn't working with the issue comment payloads rather than a problem with the webhook

Comment: We're using mutlibranch pipeline to discover PRs and branches, so it has discovered the master branch, but I guess the issues look like a PR to Jenkins (i.e. PRs and issues share ID space) but there isn't a corresponding branch so it makes sense that Jenkins isn't reacting. I guess I would need Jenkins to equate any issues without a corresponding branch to the master branch which, as you say, is probably not standard and so not supported :/